# Control Kendo Script Position Rendering in MVC

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm using the Kendo ASP.NET MVC wrappers.  I noticed the wrappers are rendering the scripts to initialize the controls immediately after the control markup.  Is there a way to configure to have the scripts render at the bottom?  Before, with the Telerik ASP.NET MVC controls, you could have the script manager render all the initializations at the bottom.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the 2013 Q1 release, they added support for deferred scripts. You can use it like so:

```
@(Html.Kendo().AutoCompleteFor(m => m)
    .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
    .MinLength(2)
    .DataSource(config =>
        {
            config.Read(action, controller, routeValues);
            config.ServerFiltering(true);
        }).Deferred())
```

Note the `Deferred()` method in the end of the chain. Then, in your layout add the following anywhere in your markup:

```
  <!-- ... -->
  @Html.Kendo().DeferredScripts()
  </body>
</html>
```

See 
http://www.kendoui.com/forums/mvc/general-discussions/kendo-initialization-scripts-in-body-interfere-with-other-libraries.aspx for more information.

Comment: This is a truly amazing addition to kendo UI +1 brother!

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry this is not possible and could not be work-arounded. The scripts of the Kendo Wrappers for MVC are always rendered after the html wrapper of the widget.

It is mentioned in the [documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/migration/migrating-from-telerik-extensions-for-aspnet-mvc#scriptregistrar-and-stylesheetregistrar).

EDIT: This is later on possible with the deferred scripts rendereding that jrummell exiplained.

Answer (score 2):

This would be a bit of a headache, but since the wrappers generate jQuery script couldn't you generate the wrapper in a partial view, grab the resulting script and inject it into a script tag at the bottom of your page? Of course, that would mean either duplicated code or a fair amount of code to generate the workaround in a reusable way, all so the scripts end up at the bottom of the page instead of the middle.

I'm assuming this is to help with performance (best practice generally being to put your CSS at the top and scripts at the bottom)?

Comment: Yes, to help with performance.  Good idea.  Could get waaaaaayyy messy depending on the output, but good idea. +1