# Kendo UI for ASP.NET Core - kendo is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, asp.net-core-mvc, kendo-ui-mvc

I keep getting the following error when I try to create a Grid or a Chart using Kendo UI. A simple ComboBox will work, though. We are using the commercial lisence and downloaded the js and css from Telerik's website while authenticated.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: kendo is not defined
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

**Config: _Layout.cshtml**

```
<head>
    <environment names="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/kendo-ui/styles/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/kendo-ui/styles/kendo.bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    </environment>
    <environment names="Staging,Production">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
        <link rel="stylesheet"
              href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.504/styles/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-href="~/lib/kendo-ui/styles/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-test-class="k-common-test-class"
              asp-fallback-test-property="opacity" asp-fallback-test-value="0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet"
              href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.504/styles/kendo.bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-href="~/lib/kendo-ui/styles/kendo.bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-test-class="k-theme-test-class"
              asp-fallback-test-property="opacity" asp-fallback-test-value="0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    </environment>
</head>
    <environment names="Development">
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/kendo-ui/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/kendo-ui/js/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>
    <environment names="Staging,Production">
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha384-K+ctZQ+LL8q6tP7I94W+qzQsfRV2a+AfHIi9k8z8l9ggpc8X+Ytst4yBo/hH+8Fk">
        </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa">
        </script>
        <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.504/js/kendo.all.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/kendo-ui/js/kendo.all.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.kendo">
        </script>
        <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.504/js/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/kendo-ui/js/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="kendo.data.transports['aspnetmvc-ajax']">
        </script>
        <script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>
```

**_ViewImports.cshtml**

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

**View.cshtml**

```
<div class="invoice-charts-container">
  <h3>Invoice History Week Totals</h3>
  <div class="demo-section k-content wide">
    @(Html.Kendo().Chart()
        .Name("chart")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 400px;" })
        .Title("Site Visitors Stats /thousands/")
        .Legend(legend => legend
            .Position(ChartLegendPosition.Bottom)
        )
        .SeriesDefaults(seriesDefaults => seriesDefaults
            .Column().Stack(true)
        )
        .Series(series =>
        {
            series.Column(new double[] { 56000, 63000, 74000, 91000, 117000, 138000 }).Name("Total Visits");
            series.Column(new double[] { 52000, 34000, 23000, 48000, 67000, 83000 }).Name("Unique visitors");
        })
        .CategoryAxis(axis => axis
            .Categories("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun")
            .MajorGridLines(lines => lines.Visible(false))
        )
        .ValueAxis(axis => axis
            .Numeric()
            .Line(line => line.Visible(false))
        )
        .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
            .Visible(true)
            .Format("{0}")
        )
    )
  </div>
  <div class="box wide">
    <div class="box-col">
      <h4>API Functions</h4>
      <ul class="options">
        <li>
          <input id="typeColumn" name="seriesType"
                 type="radio" value="column" checked="checked" autocomplete="off" />
          <label for="typeColumn">Columns</label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input id="typeBar" name="seriesType"
                 type="radio" value="bar" autocomplete="off" />
          <label for="typeBar">Bars</label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input id="typeLine" name="seriesType"
                 type="radio" value="line" autocomplete="off" />
          <label for="typeLine">Lines</label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input id="stack" type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" checked="checked" />
          <label for="stack">Stacked</label>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <p>
        <strong>refresh()</strong> will be called on each configuration change
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".options").bind("change", refresh);
        $(document).bind("kendo:skinChange", updateTheme);
    });

    function refresh() {
        var chart = $("#chart").data("kendoChart"),
            series = chart.options.series,
            type = $("input[name=seriesType]:checked").val(),
            stack = $("#stack").prop("checked");

        for (var i = 0, length = series.length; i < length; i++) {
            series[i].stack = stack;
            series[i].type = type;
        };

        chart.refresh();
    }

    function updateTheme() {
        $("#chart").getKendoChart().setOptions({ theme: kendoTheme });
    }
  </script>
</div>
```

Here is where the error occurs in the DOM:`

> Uncaught ReferenceError: kendo is not defined

```
<script>kendo.syncReady(function(){jQuery("#chart").kendoChart(
```

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

```
<script>
    
$(document).ready

(function() {
            $(".options").bind("change", refresh);
            $(document).bind("kendo:skinChange", updateTheme);
        });
```

**EDIT** - It seems the javascript files are loaded but the errors are happening anyway:[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When I had this problem, after upgrading an existing project to 2017.2.504, it was because I had my scripts defined in the body... Like you.

They have to be in the head. Here's the response I got from support:

*kendo.syncReady was introduced to address a major issue with jQuery 3.1.1 and the way Kendo UI widgets are generated on the client when using the MVC wrappers. This change, however, requires that Kendo UI script files are referenced in the page head section (this has been the default instruction for Kendo UI references in the past, as well). Please, try moving your Kendo UI references to the  tag, after the jQuery files are referenced and let me know if the error keeps occurring.*

Comment: Why does it have to be in the head? Why does it matter where it is?

Comment: @xr280xr It probably has something to do with ensuring that the javascript is in place super early in the lifecycle... However, you can get around it by using .Deferred(): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15311648/control-kendo-script-position-rendering-in-mvc .

Answer (score 3):

Adding to what @Brian MacKay already mentioned, you have the possibility to defer script output:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker().Name("datepicker").Deferred())
```

When you're using `.Deferred()`, you'll store the rendered JavaScript and you'll have the possibility to place this deferred script wherever you want:

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- stuff -->
    @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker().Name("datepicker").Deferred(true)) 
    <!-- other stuff -->
   <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.223/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.223/js/kendo.web.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.223/js/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.223/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script> 
    @Html.Kendo().DeferredScripts()
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a development box, prefix all `src` and `href` attributes that start with `https://` to use `//:`.  Chances are high that your development environment is not using SSL, so it can't use any resources over SSL links (javascript **won't** load at all!).  The prefix change will make the urls inherit whatever the page is using.

See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-src-http)

Comment: Please see my edit as the Javascript files do actually load.

Comment: Your post would seem to indicate that jQuery's not loading.

Comment: I opened Google Chrome's Web Dev Tools and I got a HTTP 200 OK for jquery.js